# What about the clothes? (Who/what gets disintegrated?)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

So, I realize this is potentially delving into the trivial, but is there any explanation given anywhere  -- in the film, the comics, or any commentary by the production staff -- which explains why

> Thanos' snap of the fingers after assembling all the Infinity Stones and disintegrating half of the people in the universe

should affect people's clothing and other personal effects?

Is it because this is just what Thanos chose to do?  Or is it built into the power?  Does the magic involved have some notion of what constitutes a person which includes their nearby stuff?   What?

Comment: Well, why shouldn't it?

Comment: @Adamant:   Well, why should it?   The simplest interpretation of the act disintegrates the people.   The clothes aren't part of the person.   Why should it disintegrate their stuff?   It doesn't disintegrate their vehicles, but it does disintegrate their weapons (I think).   So it's not obvious what should happen.   Is it up to Thanos' intent?

Comment: Magic always has to make choices. Does it want to destroy a person’s hair? Their nails? Their bionic arm? Their last meal? Thanos might have made that choice, or the gauntlet might have made it for him, but the choice was made.

Comment: @Adamant:  Okay, then where was the choice made?

Comment: Why should we know it ^ (or even care)? Filmmakers chose to disintegrate people with everything on them, and that's how, for example, teleportation works and other magic usually too. It would be rather silly if random pieces of stuff fell down where people stood, quite anticlimactic.

Comment: @Mithoron:  [Not necessarily](https://youtu.be/fK3GV-MU5pc?t=11m9s)

Comment: To the two people who VTC for "unclear what you're asking":  What is unclear about it?  I've stated plainly in the question as well as in the comments that I'm asking whether the determination of what disintegrates or doesn't is based on something about the power itself, some intelligence in the stones, the will of Thanos or merely suspension of disbelief?   What?

Comment: @Mithoron [Not necessarily, evidence #2](https://youtu.be/rYGWG2_PB_Q?t=53)

Comment: To hand-wavers and "why should we care about this" commenters: have you considered which website you're currently browsing? The whole raison d'etre of scifi.se is to ask and answer these questions :P

Comment: Probably to ensure they have clothing to come back with instead of Disney filming shots where 3.5 billion people on Earth alone are naked.

Comment: As I recall, in the comics, we see a series of panels with Thanos' head and upper torso with a star field in the background; he snaps his fingers; and in the next panel, the star field is only in half the panel (the other half is black, represented the half of the universe he destroyed). Of course, the motivation in the comics was as an offering to his beloved, a personification of Death.

Comment: did the atom bombs obliterate clothes also or did just the people get destroyed and their accouterments left alone? Seems a similar level of destruction happening

Comment: Atom bombs destroy pretty much everything, not just people or people+clothes.  Your point really doesn't apply.

Comment: @Adamant It's inconsistent. Fury's transmitter didn't get disintegrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my [**own answer on M&TV**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93065/why-did-the-accessories-clothings-masks-equipments-etc-vanish-along-the-pe)

According to the directors it's because...

### Those items are part of their identity

> Avengers: Infinity War's directors Anthony Russo and Joe Russo (who also directed Captain America: The Winter Soldier, Captain America: Civil War, and Avengers 4) revealed why objects like Spider-Man's suit, Star-Lord's clothing, and other material or weapons being carried or worn by heroes disappeared with them after Thanos snapped his fingers. According to Joe Russo, the objects faded with the heroes and other victims of Thanos erasure because they are **"part of their identity."**
>
> Anthony Russo chimed in: **"Whatever was elemental to somebody’s presence went with them."**
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/25/avengers-infinity-war-clothes-disappear-snap/)</sup>

Whether this is logical *in-universe* is open to debate but *out-of-universe* it make sense.

> Firstly this would have involved another round of complicated SFX in a movie already packed with fiddly technical requirements.
>
> Secondly it would have looked a little messy, and possibly a little silly, on screen if leather and spandex suits, helmets, clever gadgets and all that lovely Wakandan metalwork all clanked down.
>
> The Russo brothers do not really make a compelling argument for their vision in these scenes, but they definitely made the correct stylistic choice.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/967258/Avengers-Infinity-War-plot-What-happen-to-CLOTHES-in-The-Snap-who-dies)</sup>