# What happened to the planets Thanos already culled?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*

> Thanos snaps his fingers and half the population of the universe is destroyed.

We also know that

> Thanos has destroyed half the Asgardians, half of Gamora's people and half of many more civilisations already through the old fashioned method of having them shot.

So are those civilisations immune to the effect of his actions or are they impacted a second time?

Comment: This would seem to be a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187213/what-about-the-clothes) which essentially boils down to "how is it determined who/what gets disintegrated?"

Comment: @ThePopMachine You seem to be asking something else ("how did Thanos distinguish people from their clothes?", or "organic vs inorganic stuff", etc). This is asking whether the same people could be culled twice; if anything, a subquestion of "how did Thanos choose his victims?".

Comment: @AndresF.:   It has been well-established, even though I don't personally agree with it, that a question whose answer answers a different question is considered a duplicate.   In this case, it's quite clear that an answer to the question "what determines what gets disintegrated?" will answer this question because the answer is probably something like "The magic decides based on Thanos' intent." or "It's already established that the Stones have some *will* or *intelligence*, so that's what decides"  or something .

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'm aware of that consensus (and I also disagree with it, like you), but what I'm saying is that I disagree that an answer to the other question will necessarily answer this one. For example, "because the power of the Infinity Gauntlet only affects organic matter, and for the purpose of simplification all clothes are assumed to be inorganic" would answer the second question but not this one (not saying that is the real answer, mind you!). Also, "what" and "who" are similar, but not the same, and can get different answers :)

Comment: @AndresF. \*organic -> inorganic??   It's the other way around which changes the conclusion.   In this case, I just don't see it.   [This comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187213/what-about-the-clothes-who-what-gets-disintegrated#comment508974_187213) rings true and that answer is likely to apply to both.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yes, sorry, change my hypothetical answer to "because the cull doesn't distinguish inorganic from organic, because <reasons>". It still wouldn't work as an answer for both questions. The comment you linked to seems like a non-answer to me :) The point is, can you see a potentially correct answer that would work for your question but wouldn't answer this one? If yes, then they aren't duplicates. If no, then they could be dupes, but... in that case it seems to me you have already decided the correct answer to your question :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who decides which half of the universe should be destroyed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed)

Comment: Voted to leave open, since neither question is likely to answer this, which is specific to the planets Thanos already decimated (halfimated?).  Pop's question is about something completely unrelated, and the possible dupe is about who decides with neither current answer related to this question.

Comment: @DaveJohnson:   Sorry, but per policy, this question is a duplicate of one of the other two.   Again, it's not about whether the **question** is different, it's about whether the **answer** to one will satisfy the other.  I don't agree with it, but it's how it is.

Comment: @DaveJohnson:   The answer to the other question is "It appears to be determined by the wielder."   From that, it is obvious that we should conclude that the answer to this question is that the already affected planets are not affected again, because Thanos is measured and reasonable (at least to the extent it makes sense in this context).   The other answer answers this question.   End of story.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Your interpretation of the policy seems wrong (as I explained in my comments above). I agree with Dave Johnson. Neither questions seem like, if answered, they would *automatically* also answer this question. If you disagree, you can always take it to meta.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Why would it be obvious? I wouldn't even say that his reasoning for his original culling was obvious. After all, he continued (both before and after snap) to cull civilisations that 1) had already gone through a catastrophic event, 2) had no concern of overpopulation, especially thanks to 1, 3) couldn't even be considered part of a specific civilisation.

Comment: @DariM:  You're merely questioning his logic, which I agree is highly doubtful.   I'm saying it's obvious what his interpretation of the what needs to be done means.   Did he go back and cull a planet again after already doing it?   No.   Did he cull planets that weren't at risk of overpopulation?   Yes.  It is quite clear this the only rule for him is "Kill half of people regardless of everything else."   That means that if a planet was already culled, he wouldn't do it again....

Comment: So if the power acts according to his intent, then are not culled again.   If the power acts differently (all he can do is give the Stones a vague order "kill 50%"), then perhaps they are.    Bottom line:   I'm saying that how Thanos **would want the power applied** is obvious.

Comment: "I'm saying it's obvious what his interpretation of the what needs to be done means. Did he go back and cull a planet again after already doing it? No." We do not have any evidence to back this up one way or the other in the MCU. The only "fact" we have is that he claims Gamora's planet is a paradise, but we don't even know if that is an actual truth/fact, whether he did multiple culls to get there, etc., since we aren't shown it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TLDR**

- We don't know yet...
- One can assume the stones know the intent of the user
- There is a good chance that a second attack would not occur

There is no evidence yet addressing what has happened. The only effects we have seen from Thanos' actions affected the heroes we have come to love. Beyond this we don't know.

However, based on the events of the film we may have some idea of the result:

> We know that Thanos simply is trying to help everyone out by reducing the strain on the universe's finite resources. That is his plan and his motivation; to keep the rest of the universe from befalling a fate similar to his home planet...

During the events of the film:

> We also know that when engaging the Guardians on Knowhere Thanos was manipulating reality in real time. I do not remember who but of Drax and Mantis he turned one into blocks and the other into strips, an homage to the comics as I understand it. (I think the characters were affected in that order respectively). Whether this was done intentionally by Thanos or how the stone understood his desire is unclear, but either way the stone acted based upon his desires in the situation. He wanted those characters to not be a threat so he could "consult" with Gamora and Quill. I feel pretty safe in my assumption that Thanos was not thinking "I want there to be (this many) blocks of him exactly (this big) and (this many) strips of her (exactly this wide and long) falling to the floor. Unless he did, the stone took some artistic license in its actions, but the desire was still adhered to.

Considering your question:

> Given that interaction I think it would be safe to assume that the gauntlet as a whole would act similarly. If it did exactly as Thanos desired to the letter then the only reason those societies would be affected again is if he desired it to be so. Despite his hardliner actions Thanos is still acting... rationally... so I would not see those civilizations affected again. If the gauntlet acts without specific direction from its wielder then it would take the subconscious desires into account when acting and again, I would not see those civilizations affected.

Comment: Speaking of Drax... his planet had been culled, yet he was still effected by the snap...

Comment: Good point... Maybe because technically he wasn't on a planet that had been culled before?

Comment: But maybe if Gamora's planet had its population halved again, it would get *even nicer!!* Worth a try, surely!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @enumaris's comment in the linked dupe question:

> Drax disappeared and iirc his species was previously culled (hence his hatred for Thanos)...so it would appear that at least his species got cut in half again. Not sure about the others. – *enumaris Jan 9 at 23:55*

Absent direct canon answer, this points to the fact that Drax's species was halved **again**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that since he only destroyed half of each of the planet's populations, the other half is fine. I am backed up with the conversation between Gamora and Thanos about her home planet, which goes something along the lines of:

> Thanos: You were poor, always scraping for food with a growling belly each night. Your childhood was miserable. But the children now know nothing of hunger. They go to bed each night with a full stomach and their childhood is a happy one.

I don't know if these are his exact words, and he might have destroyed some of the other planets, but he has clear, defined motives to basically solve overpopulation (in an extreme way).

Comment: Welcome to SciFi! I think you might be misinterpreting the question. The question isn't what happened after Thanos visited and wiped out half the population, pre Infinity War. The asker is asking if they were immune from the second round, when Thanos killed half of the population, *everywhere*.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! As @Gnemlock has said you appear to have misinterpreted the question, or at least the dialogue from that scene. However, this is a nice attempt at a first answer and we'd be more than happy to keep you around! Don't forget to register your account and take the [tour]!