# Avengers Infinity War - Were any deaths caused by Thanos' snap calculated into the 50% or were they collateral damage?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

After the Thanos' snap at the end of *Infinity War* we see Nick Fury witnessing a helicopter crashing into a building...

Assuming the crash was caused by the pilot(s) being a part of the 50% of the snapped population can we count possible extra deaths of the situation, such as passengers and/or people inside the building it crashed into, as part of the 50% as well? (And of course, what of any similar deaths across the universe? If any extraneous deaths caused by the snap were not considered then ultimately the snap would have caused slightly more than 50% of populations being killed by the snapping right?)

Comment: Which 50% are you taking about? The one the heroes always talk about, or the "real" one in this scenario?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that Thanos doesn't take into account additional deaths. They're just collateral damage.

Comment: @Jenayah - The OP is referring to the 50% of the population that Thanos killed with his snap.

Comment: @Odin1806 that's not entirely clear from the question. Sure, the heroes always talk about "50%" who got killed by Thanos, but the way I read it Kasper wants to know whether that figure should actually be 60% instead or something? We can't really know without OP's input. Waiting for a rephrasing :)

Comment: @Jenayah - Not really. Thanos said all along he killed 50% of the population randomly for the sake of limited resources. That was his goal. The OP is asking if those killed in collateral damage (i.e. passengers in a car accident when the driver is snapped) are included in that 50% or if they would be just that, collateral damage. Seems clear to me.

Comment: "The OP is referring to the 50% of the population that Thanos killed with his snap" Yes, that's what I was talking about.

We might also assume the 50 % of the snap were the ones that fell apart into dust, the collateral damage were extra's. As with the helicopter, it was possible no one else was onboard, no one was in the spot in the building where it crashed and no one was hit by debris.

Comment: Wouldn't you then have to count living things that were going to die but *didn't* as a result of the snap? Like a plant being eaten by a deer, a warthog being chased by a lion, or a human who was about to be killed by a murderer? And how would you then deal with a situation in which the victim was saved, but was so wounded that it died later?

Comment: @Kasper - I did some heavy edits to your question to attempt to clarify what you are asking. I would like to confirm the edits are still in line with your original question. Hopefully this is the case...

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

- It is doubtful they have been included.
- Those "chosen" left behind no evidence.
- I think it depends on what Thanos was considering when he snapped.
- Either way, we don't know 100% for sure...

At the moment of the snap those "chosen" by the stones to perish were turned to dust temporarily and then left no evidence behind. That is how those unlucky individuals were removed from the universe.

While anything from before the snap (momentum of the car they were driving, their baseball glove they left on the stoop, etc.) still existed, the snap itself erased the individuals as though they never existed at that exact moment. Once the dust fully dissipated there was no evidence of the individual left behind at all.

It is possible the time stone knew those that would have been killed as a result of the snap and calculated those deaths into the 50%, but to be counted among the 50% I feel they should have been "dusted" along with all the others... Feels sloppy to leave behind the bodies if they were counted among the 50%...

I do not remember evidence from the films that shows dead bodies left behind or discussions of the aftermath proving my theory, but that also begs the question of how long after the snap should the ripple spread? For example: What if a someone's caregiver was snapped? Would the person who starves to death days later be counted among the 50% as well? Paralyzed people, babies, etc... Maybe that is why the "snap" took so long. Not just accounting for everyone across the galaxy, but checking their futures as well...

Though that all being said, as I stated in my other [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187369/what-happened-to-the-planets-thanos-already-culled/187460#187460) about Thanos snapping, if he was considering those situations when he snapped, even subconsciously, the stones would have considered his desires and acted accordingly.