# What happened to those indirectly killed by the Snap?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-endgame, avengers-infinity-war

Based on the images that are shown right after the Snap, there seems to be a lot of deaths that are side effects of the snap. Everyone who was on a plane when the pilot went away, people in cars, and similar situations.

Those were, strictly speaking, natural deaths, so the question is: were those deaths reversed and brought back by Banner's snap or would they stay dead?

I’m not taking here about people that died before the Snap (i.e. Vision, etc) but about people that died *after* the Snap, *because* of the Snap, but without being “willed out of existence”.

Comment: >>but were not “willed out of existence”.

This is actually questionable. I doubt anyone knows what the actual 'will' (read 'wish') was... but if it was that 'as a result' X percent of all sentient beings would cease to exist, it might well have included those who were killed.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate of your own past question. Could you clarify if these are different if I’ve misunderstood something?

Comment: I have a similar question myself but it asks about the likes of presnap causalities (I.e. Vision) but I was watching it the other day and I was thinking: “oh, it sucks for all the people on that plane”

Comment: The answer is the same to pre and post Snap deaths and I’m pretty sure my answer on the dupe covers it well enough. You also don’t specifically state pre Snap in the dupe.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, I didn’t read the other one carefully enough. You can at least say I’m consistent the things that bother me... it just feels so unfair

Comment: [This question is also related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/avengers-infinity-war-were-any-deaths-caused-by-thanos-snap-calculated-into-t)

Comment: “The answer is the same to pre and post Snap deaths” — is it? I don't think the answer on Jorge Cordoba's question addresses that. The quote from Markus is answering a question specifically about Loki and Vision, who did not die as a knock-on result of the Snap.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite _”I mean we only brought back the people who were effectively disintegrated by the Snap at the end of Infinity War.”_  that seems pretty explicit to me.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: when answering a different question though. It's possible Markus hadn't even thought about people indirectly killed by the Snap when saying that. Screenwriters aren't rule machines, they're human beings.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Sure it's possible but I think you're overthinking it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: which is kind of the point of this site!