# Did The Decimation avoid previously halved populations?

Tags: avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones, thanos, asgard

Prior to and during the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*, the Mad Titan Thanos massacres half of many different populations - including Morag, Xandar, and Asgard. However, when Thanos obtained all six Infinity Stones, he was able to kill 50% of the entire population of the universe in one snap. (Side note: this event is referenced as The Decimation.) However, multiple populations had already been "taken care of" by Thanos and the Children of Thanos. Were these populations halved again by The Decimation?

Comment: "this event is referenced as The Decimation" — is it? When? Shouldn't it be the Semimation?

Comment: Also presumably it's up to Thanos, as it's his wish. He may have been a bit distracted by Stormbreaker in his chest, but he had been planning this thing for a while, so maybe he included the necessary caveats and codicils.

Comment: Dupe of [What happened to the planets Thanos already culled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187369/what-happened-to-the-planets-thanos-already-culled)