# Is Drax's Species Extinct?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

All in the title -- Are there other living members of Drax's species? When were they culled?

This question has a partial answer, which I have issue with --

[What happened to the planets Thanos already culled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187369/what-happened-to-the-planets-thanos-already-culled/215945#215945)

The issue I have is, didn't Ronan the Accuser cull Drax's homeworld, not Thanos? Ronan doesn't seem to have any interest in the whole "Kill only half" school of thought - Especially after what happened at the end of GotG Volume 1. (Attempted annihilation of Xandar?)

I mostly ask because

(Guardians 3 spoiler below)

> Drax knows a language not in Nebula's databank. I figure extinct civilizations may be removed.

Comment: on being asked about the language James Gunn responded - "Drax knew the language from his childhood. It's not in anyone's translators." per https://screenrant.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-3-james-gunn-questions-answered/

Comment: As long as Drax is alive, the answer is no.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish a sexual-reproducing species is functionally extinct when only one member remains.

Comment: I don't think Drax comes from a different species.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I had thought about editing the title because of people like you.

Comment: Frame challenge: Why would an extinct language be removed? Typically, recordings and past research is still around and stays around, if only to be able to reconstruct its influence on non-extinct languages.

Comment: There was also nothing in GOTG3 to indicate that the language spoken by the children was Drax's native language.  He just happened to know the language.

Comment: @JK. Yeah, but it happened in the middle of a convo about how dumb he is. Either he's not as dumb as he seems, or he's just in possession of dumb luck that the few things he knows are absurdly useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We learn from the Director's Audio Commentary for *Infinity War* that Drax's planet was culled (by Ronan, operating under orders from Thanos) but there's no indication that his people were subsequently annihilated.

> **Anthony Russo**: *This is a call-back to Drax's history with Thanos here ... His planet was treated the same was as Gamora's planet. Drax was put on one side and his family was put on the other*

Comment: I see. . . That makes sense. Ronan didn't decide to completely annihilate Xandar until after he had the power to disobey Thanos.

Comment: But you don't have to annihilate a whole planet to make a language go extinct. And if it was only ever a spoken language amongst a particular tribe...

Comment: @Pam - And while that's true, the question isn't asking why this language isn't in her databank, it's asking whether his people are extinct, which they don't appear to be

Comment: I always hesitate with the Word of God answers. No background Kylosians have ever been seen? Alas, Valorum gets the check again.