# Why did this happen to Thanos's ships at the end of "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, when Tony Stark

> snaps the Infinity Gauntlet v2, all of Thanos's *ships* also get disintegrated. The Chitauri Leviathans are living beasts, so it makes sense, but the [Outrider Dropships](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Outrider_Dropship) are clearly mechanical, as seen in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

We did not see this with the snap in *Avengers: Infinity War*, where

> only living things were dusted.

Why is it different this time around?

See 2m35s of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgN5XY2LkAI), ignore the Chitauri Leviathan in the foreground.

Comment: “the Infinity Gauntlet v2” — I think it's kind of version 3 at that point, or at least 2.1.

Comment: The clothes of the people who disappeared were not living things in most cases, yet they disappeared as well.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The Snap just performs the wielder’s will which is made quite clear over the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame*. It’s made the most clear when Tony asks Smart Hulk what to do with his Snap.

> **Tony:** You remember... everyone Thanos snapped away five years ago and just bringing them back to now, today. Don't change anything from the last five years.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Later on when Smart Hulk has done his Snap he again makes it clear that he had control over what the Snap did because he tried to bring Nat back.

> **Smart Hulk:** You know, I tried. When I had the gauntlet, the stones, I really tried to bring her back.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Just to be complete Thanos’ Snap was only to kill half of all life and so that is why it didn’t affect ships or the like.

> **Gamora:** The entire time I knew Thanos, he only ever had one goal: To bring balance to the Universe by wiping out half of all life. He used to kill people planet by planet, massacre by massacre...
>
> [...]
>
> **Thanos:** Little one, it's a simple calculus. This universe is finite, its resources finite. If life is left unchecked, life will cease to exist. It needs correction.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

The implication is then that Tony’s Snap was to destroy Thanos, his forces and equipment so that they could win the battle. A deleted scene shows Gamora is still alive and she was originally on Thanos’ side and so the Snap must have only been for those loyal to Thanos at the time of the Snap.

And of course the Snap can affect none living things as we see in all of the Snaps. In Thanos' first one it destroys clothes and "personal items" of those who are Snapped. In his second one he destroys the Infinity Stones.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Where are the stones?
>
> **Thanos:** Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> **Bruce Banner:** You used them two days ago!
>
> **Thanos:** I used the stones to destroy the stones. It nearly killed me. But the work is done. It always will be. I am... inevitable.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Then in Smart Hulk's Snap he just reverts Thanos' Snap which brings back the clothing, personal items etc. Lastly, Tony's Snap affects clothing, ships and the like.

Comment: Every instance of the Gauntlet's use has revolved around either killing life or bringing it back. Is the Gauntlet able to have the same impact, at universe-scale, on non-living objects?

Comment: @ElleFie That is what we are led to believe but yeah I don’t think we’ve seen that yet.

Comment: @ElleFie Or reducing the stones to their constituent atoms (action not shown, but the aftermath was)

Comment: @Chronocidal Aye that's not on a universal scale (in terms of distance) but it is a good example of the Stones affecting none living objects.

Comment: @ElleFie Thanos intended to use another Snap to destroy and remake the entire universe, so he, at least, believed they could do so. It is possible that he might have been mistaken about this (he hadn't experienced his "original" self almost dying from using the Stones to destroy themselves, and that might have made him think differently about things), but we can't be sure about that.

Comment: `Then in Smart Hulk's Snap he just reverts Thanos' Snap` I wonder if that could include bringing back the stones from their timeline... hmmmm

Comment: @Kapler I don’t quite follow what you mean to be honest. If you mean it’d reverse the Time Heist I don’t see why it would.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot OG Thanos used the stones to destroy the stones in the OG timeline. They went to other timelines to get the stones from the other timelines (and then later returned them to their respective timelines, leaving no stones in OG timeline). I'm just speculating that Hulk's snap might have also (maybe unknowingly) un-done OG Thanos' destruction of the OG stones.

Comment: @Kapler That seems highly unlikely considering what the Snap was for. However, if they need to for plot reasons I’m sure they could have it happen.

Comment: @ElleFie "Every instance of the Gauntlet's use has revolved around either killing life or bringing it back".  That's not accurate.  Thanos is wearing the gauntlet on Nowhere while he uses the Reality Stone to remake the condition of the Collector's building to deceive the Guardians of the Galaxy, and later when he remakes it again to reveal its "true" condition.  He also uses the gauntlet to throw a moon at Iron Man.

Comment: @tbrookside I think that comment was talking solely about when using **all** of the Stones.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Perhaps.  But it really wouldn't be rational in-universe if adding more infinity stones to the gauntlet made it *less* powerful.

Comment: @tbrookside A better question would be how would anyone *know* what powers one could harness by possessing all the Stones?  According to Ebony Maw, Thanos is the first person in history to have ever had possession of more than one of them.

Answer (score 86):

The snap is just the trigger to have the stones carry out your will, whatever it may be.

Thanos wanted to destroy half of all life so that's what happened. Stark wanted to destroy Thanos' invasion force which included their ships and technology so that is what happened.

Comment: Duplicating my reply to @TheLethalCarrot: Every instance of the Gauntlet's use has revolved around either killing life or bringing it back. Is the Gauntlet able to have the same impact, at universe-scale, on non-living objects?

Comment: In the MCU it was also used to destroy the infinity gems. So of the 4 uses seen 2 of them affected inanimate objects. In the comics it was used for relatively mundane things like teleportation or adjusting the orbit of earth. There is no indication in the MCU or comics that the gauntlet can only be used to kill or bring back life.

Comment: @JohnMeacham technically all the Snaps affected inanimate objects too as “close, personal” items were Snapped away too: such as clothes. (At least I think that was the wording used).

Comment: @ElleFie Only because that's what Thanos wanted to do, and the Avengers wanted to undo. If Thanos' mission was to eradicate all machines then the Avengers snap would be to bring all the machines back, and you would be asking why Tony's snap was capable of killing Thanos and his army when so far it was only shown to affect machines.

Comment: @ElleFie I think The Gauntlet can do whatever the writers wants it to do, considering it has all the infinity stones, covering everything possible in the entire universe. So it seems it's up the will/imagination of whoever wields it.

Comment: @ElleFie the Gauntlet can do literally anything you want (within the confines of its home Universe).

Comment: @OrangeDog With the Multiverse not _really_ being a thing yet in the MCU the _"within the confines of its home Universe"_ restraint doesn't seem to have been added yet. Now that the Infinity Stones are destroyed I doubt it will be in the MCU and so is probably just a comic thing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It's actually really interesting what was and was not dusted in the Snap.  E.g. most weapons carried by dusted people disappeared (see Bucky, Quill), but not all (see Clint's daughter - the bow she was carrying was dropped).  The Pyms were wearing headsets that were not dusted when they were.  Nick Fury's modified pager managed to not be dusted with him.  Seems to be just "whatever is convenient to the filmmakers"...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's something to do with "close personal items", see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/198653/58193) with the interview quote in it. So clothes and personal weapons are affected but his daughter's bow probably wasn't a close or personal item, the same goes for the headset. The pager is the only case that doesn't really seem to fit to be honest. (And out of universe clothes makes sense so they don't have to show naked people).

Comment: I would've thought, for example, that Spider-Man's suit might not have counted - that's a new suit he'd only had for a couple hours, and he was wearing street-clothes underneath it, so you wouldn't have the nudity problem in that case.  Likewise, Bucky was given that arm on the morning of the battle at Wakanda, so he hasn't had it for long.  Whereas Fury's been holding onto that pager for decades...  As for the bow, I figured it was actually Clint's bow, she was just using it.  So it stayed because Clint stayed, but that brings up all kinds of other potential complications...

Answer (score 8):

There's no reason to believe the Stones aren't capable of eliminating non-living objects. When Thanos did his snap, it removed half of the population of the universe, yes. But it also removed their clothes, their smartphones, their nails and hair... all over the universe.

So yup, the Stones are perfectly capable of eliminating non-living stuff all over the universe, and they do what you tell them to do. Thanos wanted to eliminate half the life in the universe (including their clothes), Tony did what Tony wanted to do, which incidentally was on a much smaller scale (a few ships in close vicinity).

As a bonus, we've seen the damage a single Stone did in *Guardians of the Galaxy* - once, in the stories of how the Stones were used in the past (destroying entire planets), once in the destruction of the Collector's base, and finally, with the threat of what Ronan wanted to do to Nova Prime using just the single Stone (again, destroying the entire planet). We're led to believe that simply having the Stone touch the ground would be enough. We don't know if it would actually work and if the stories were accurate, so this is a side-note compared to actually seeing what Thanos actually did, universe-wide.

Answer (score 4):

### They're Infinity Stones, not living creatures only Stones

While it's true the Soul Stone and Mind Stone are related to characteristics of beings, that hardly limits the Stones' ability.  They could dust a Plymouth Duster if you set your mind to it.

Further, it's not clear that "dusting" means "annihilation", in fact, the return of the Blipped suggests that they went into some sort of purgatory.

It's possible that Stark sent them back in time from whence they came, while removing any knowledge of the Time Heist.  Since everyone who knew about Nebula'23's incursion was present there at the Stark Snap, that should suffice.

Comment: I don't see any reason a "purgatory" is suggested. They just didn't exist in the interim.